# How to logically layout the relationship for models in a typical Marketplace platform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

I am new to Rails, ORM and database building. I am currently building a 2 sided marketplace platform like AirBnb, but I am not quite sure how to lay out the relationships between the models properly for this type of platform, like one_to_many rel or such.

Here is what I wish to achieve.

Customer can signup, create an account/login/profile -> User Table

Customer can generate a request/order, such as, food order, cleaning order, etc -->??

the other gets displayed to service workers, who fits the criteria for the order, if the worker is a cook, then he/she gets to see all of the orders related to food order, sorted by cost, requirement, etc.

I am not really sure how to map out the association of these 3 models... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :worker

  scope :for_cook, where("category == cook")
  scope :for_cleaner, where("category == cleaner")
end
```

Then when you want the list of all orders that a cook can fulfill:

```
available_cook_orders = Order.for_cook
```

And you'd add additional logic to handle the other criteria you mentioned (cost, etc.)